# "909 Application authentication failure. HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized" while downloading Blackberry app to device

Tags: blackberry

After signing and preparing the blackberry application build very properly, I uploaded the build to the server.

Now I try to download the application through my device using BB external browser.

If I click on the link it brings me to the download control, but on clicking the download button it pops up a dialog box telling download failed which further leads to a message:-

"909 Application authentication failure. HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"

I tried preparing the build again but it is not helping. Signing process is completed properly.

I am using new signing keys as well.

Comment: you tried via desktop manager ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a problem with your server configuration for Over the Air deployment. Are you using Basic authentication for downloads? If that's the case, [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Over-The-Air-OTA-Authentication-htaccess-htpasswd-Error-401/td-p/465087) could help you (see the last answer).

Answer (score 3):

An HTTP 401 error indicates that the web resource you are trying to access (presumably your application) requires user authentication. Check the configuration of your web server. From [w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
>   relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
>   explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access
>   Authentication"

Answer (score 0):

You can check your internet connection and all required files are signing or not.

If everything is OK, then order new keys from blackberry and replace old signing keys by these keys.